# Find error location in tex file with inputs

Tags: errors, compiling, texmaker, input

I am using `TexMaker`. I have a document with dozens of `input` files. There is one main tex file, with inputs for each chapter. Each chapter may have at the same time other inputs. 
Now I have an error when trying to compile the pdf. The message/log points out the line of the fault but not to which file it belongs to so I cannot find the error. For example, in the picture below, is there any way to know the filename of the line 455 to which this error refers to?

[image: Error with line reference but no file reference]

Comment: Look in the .log file.

Comment: I think texmaker is usually clever enough to know the fie if you just click on the error. Otherwise you'll have to look in the log file it self, find the error and look for `./filename.tex` further above the error message.

Comment: It might also be an idea to give us more information on this particular document. I just made a test, and the file name of the error was listed in the File column. You might also want to list exactly which version of texmaker you are using. Seems I'm using an older one. (I generally use a different editor)

Comment: Thanks for your help! My TexMaker version is Texmaker 5.0.2. I found the error in the log file, which is 7000+ lines long. it would be great still to get the File in the error box.

Comment: You might need to ask the texmaker developers, there have been other problems with the 5.0.xx series. Also it might depend on your setup. At least under TeXLive you can instruct LaTeX to prefix errors with the filename, but then texmaker could no longer figure out how to parse the errors at all.